# Tor network used a little bit of my relay bandwidth. Why?

Tags: exit-relays, bandwidth

I have a Tor exit relay for about 6 months and assign 1600 KBps for `RelayBandwidthRate`. Until a week ago, used bandwidth on my relay was equal to 600-700 KBps. But in this last 6 days, used bandwidth reduced to 10 KBps. I did not change the configuration files and now I don't understand reason of this.

What events may have occurred? What is the reason?

Comment: Whats the consensus weight of your relay? It could be an issue related to the current bwauth problem.

Comment: how to get consensus weight

Comment: Go to https://globe.torproject.org and enter name/IP address/etc. of your relay. Click on the finding and you'll see the weight when you scroll down.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if your node maybe has been flagged as a BadExit, this would explain that most of the Tor-Clients would try not to use your Exitnode.

An example for an current BadExit is: tylerlockedotorg

You can see the current network status with [atlas.torproject.org](https://atlas.torproject.org/#search/tylerlockedotorg)

Answer (score -1):

This behavior is typical of a node flagged "eventually" as a Guard Node and you are not being a guard node for many clients at the moment to utilize all your bandwidth.